# Create Triangular Batch on Android card

Tags: android, android-cardview

I want to create green badge like below app.
How can I make this ?

[image]

Comment: An overlayed image with transparent areas will do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe by using a custom textview component-like and rotate it, and you put it on the top right-corner of your cardview ?

Answer (score 0):

I kept it very simple 
 1. TextView - right corner

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_special_badges"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="-80dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:background="@color/green_color"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Recommended"
        android:textColor="@color/white" />
```

2. Define Rotate 45 Degree rotate_forty_five_degree.xml

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:fillAfter="true"
   android:fromDegrees="0"
   android:pivotX="30%"
   android:toDegrees="45" />
   ```
3. Apply Rotation

   ```
   RotateAnimation rotate = (RotateAnimation)        AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(mContext, R.anim.rotate_forty_five_degree);
   holder.tvSpecialBadges.setAnimation(rotate);
   ```

below is final result
[image]